# sqlite3 is not inserting information

Tags: sqlite

I have been struggling with this problem since 3 days ago and I don't find the reason why mirar.db is no saving the information, Do you people have any clue why it's not recording? I'll appreciate your help

```
 <?php

$conexion = new SQLite3('mirar.db') or die ("Ha sido imposible establecer la conexion");
$consulta = 
 <<<SQL
CREATE TABLE if not exists inventory(StockNumber INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,Descrip      VARCHAR(50),OnHandQuan INTEGER,PackQty INTEGER,PackCost FLOAT); 
INSERT INTO inventory(StockNumber,Descrip,OnHandQuan,PackQty,PackCost)VALUES (51002,'AA Dry Cells   4 Pack',173,12,9.00); 
INSERT INTO inventory(StockNumber,Descrip,OnHandQuan,PackQty,PackCost)VALUES (51004,'AA Dry Cells  8 Pack',5,12,16.80); 
INSERT INTO inventory(StockNumber,Descrip,OnHandQuan,PackQty,PackCost)VALUES (43512,'10W-30 Motor    Oil, Quart',36,12,18.20); 
INSERT INTO inventory(StockNumber,Descrip,OnHandQuan,PackQty,PackCost)VALUES (51013,'D Dry Cells  8 Pack',19,12,90.20); 
INSERT INTO inventory(StockNumber,Descrip,OnHandQuan,PackQty,PackCost)VALUES (23155,'Shovel Pointed Long Handle',1500,1,9.82); 
INSERT INTO inventory(StockNumber,Descrip,OnHandQuan,PackQty,PackCost)VALUES (51001,'AAA Dry  Cells 4 Pack ',92,12,9.00); 
INSERT INTO inventory(StockNumber,Descrip,OnHandQuan,PackQty,PackCost)VALUES (43111,'White Gas   Gallon Can',14,4,14.75);
SQL;
//Insertar contenido en la Tabla-------
$resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);
if (!$resultado){
echo "error";}
else { echo "Tabla Mirar creada correctamente<br>\n";};

//Cerrar la Conexion-------------------
$conexion->close(); 

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your table `StockNumber` is a primary key you dont have to insert the data for it. It is added automatically.

Try to remove that and try again:

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists inventory(StockNumber INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,Descrip      VARCHAR(50),OnHandQuan INTEGER,PackQty INTEGER,PackCost FLOAT); 
INSERT INTO inventory(Descrip,OnHandQuan,PackQty,PackCost)VALUES ('AA Dry Cells   4 Pack',173,12,9.00); 
INSERT INTO inventory(Descrip,OnHandQuan,PackQty,PackCost)VALUES ('AA Dry Cells  8 Pack',5,12,16.80); 
INSERT INTO inventory(Descrip,OnHandQuan,PackQty,PackCost)VALUES ('10W-30 Motor    Oil, Quart',36,12,18.20); 
INSERT INTO inventory(Descrip,OnHandQuan,PackQty,PackCost)VALUES ('D Dry Cells  8 Pack',19,12,90.20); 
INSERT INTO inventory(Descrip,OnHandQuan,PackQty,PackCost)VALUES ('Shovel Pointed Long Handle',1500,1,9.82); 
INSERT INTO inventory(Descrip,OnHandQuan,PackQty,PackCost)VALUES ('AAA Dry  Cells 4 Pack ',92,12,9.00); 
INSERT INTO inventory(Descrip,OnHandQuan,PackQty,PackCost)VALUES ('White Gas   Gallon Can',14,4,14.75);
SQL;
```

From the [SQLLite FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1)

> Short answer: A column declared INTEGER PRIMARY KEY will
>   autoincrement.

Comment: nope, I did it as you told me and it's still not working, it creates the date "mirar.db" but when I open it it doesn't have the information. I haven't been able to find information, do you have another idea?

Comment: @JesúsDavid:- I think you are missing something. It worked for me. Check here: http://www.compileonline.com/execute_sql_online.php

Comment: Do you have installed Xampp or another php runer in your pc? Would you mind do it from there, just copy and paste that lines in a new sheet and run it :), you 'll see the message "Tabla Mirar creada correctamente" you could think it has worked but then try to look for the file"mirar.db" in my case it's in here "C:\xampp\htdocs\FavoritosOnline" so now try to open the file and you'll see it doesn't have information and I think it should have the information we want to add, Can you see now? and it's weird because you can create tables but it's not saving the information I want to INSERT.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is using $resultado = $conexion->exec($consulta);
Thanks!